# getting a substring(charset independent) between given two offsets

Tags: php, character-encoding, substring

I just want to know if there is any built in php function where I can get a substring between given two keywords (keyword1 and keyword2). Note that keywords may repeat in the string so I must be able to get  the substring between xth keyword1 and yth keyword2. Moreover, I mainly use unicode characters so the function should be charset independen.

Please help me out to handle this problem.

E.g. $string=This is their cat with a hat in the theater.
$keyword1="is";  $keyword2="the";

Task: how to get substring between 2nd occurance of "is" and 3nd occurance of "the" in the given string above.

Answer: " the cat with a hat in the "

Comment: Well, you are able to clearly define the problem. That is half the battle. What exactly is preventing you from figuring out a solution? You really should try to solve it on your own, and then ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: I tried a lot but ended up with a solution for a specific string,not in general. I want to learn short, general and best solution. I am not a php expert so I asked the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
$string = "This is their cat with a hat in the theater";

$regex1 = "/.*? is |^is/";
$regex2 = "/ the .*| the$/";
echo preg_replace($regex1, '', preg_replace($regex2, ' the', $string));
```

**EDIT** Here is more generic code:

```
function find($text, $str, $offset) {
    $len = strlen($text);
    $search_len = strlen($str);
    $count = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$len; ++$i) {
        if (substr($text, $i, $search_len) == $str) {
            if (++$count == $offset) {
                return $i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function between($text, $word1, $offset1, $word2, $offset2) {
    $start = find($text, $word1, $offset1);
    $end = find($text, $word2, $offset2);
    if ($start != -1 && $end != -1) {
        return substr($text, $start + strlen($word1), $end-$start-strlen($word2));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}


$string = "This is their cat with a hat in the theater";

echo between($string, 'is', 2, 'the', 3);
echo between($string, 'at', 1, 'at', 3);
```

Comment: jcubic, do you have a general way for that? For example how about if I want to change the offsets like 1st "at" and 3rd "at"? I need some general way like a function coz I have already found a solution for a specific string and offsets like you did above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @jcubic. Your script worked for ASCII but not for Unicode characters. You inspired me and I found the solution based on [www.phpro.org](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Find-Position-Of-Nth-Occurrence-Of-String.html)

Answer (score 0):

Combination of following two functions work for any string including unicode characters:

```
//Gets the position of a given substring with its offset;
function strposOffset($string, $search, $offset)
{
    /*** explode the string ***/
    $arr = explode($search, $string);
    /*** check the search is not out of bounds ***/
   switch( $offset )
   {
       case $offset == 0:
         return false;
         break;

       case $offset > max(array_keys($arr)):
         return false;
         break;

       default:
         return mb_strlen(implode($search, array_slice($arr, 0, $offset)), "utf-8");
   }
} //Source: www.phpro.org



//Extracts a substring between given two given substrings with their offsets.
function extractMiddleSubstr($string, $substr1, $offset1, $substr2, $offset2){

   $strlen_substr1 = mb_strlen($substr1, "utf-8"); //length of substr1;
   $strpos_substr1  = strposOffset($string, $substr1, $offset1); //position of substr1;
   $strpos_substr2  = strposOffset($string, $substr2, $offset2); //position of substr2;

    if($strpos_substr1!==null && $strpos_substr2!==null && $strpos_substr1!==false && $strpos_substr2!==false){

       if($strpos_substr1<=$strpos_substr2){

          $strpos_substr    = $strlen_substr1+$strpos_substr1; //position of substr;
          $strlen_substr  = $strpos_substr2-$strpos_substr;  //length of substr;

          $substr       = mb_substr($string, $strpos_substr, $strlen_substr, "utf-8"); //substr;
          $substr           = trim($substr); // removes whitespaces;

          return $substr;
        }else{
          return false;
        }

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```